# Android Service Process for MediaPlayer

Tags: android, service, media-player

I'm working on an app that will use MediaPlayer to play music. I'm interested in adding background functionality, so that the music continues playing indefinitely (or as long as the user wishes). The Android docs seem to be pointing me to using a Service for this sort of thing.

So my question is: Should I define a process for the service (in the manifest, by using `android:process`), or is it okay if the service will run in the same process as the UI?

On a similar note: Are there any other things I should be worrying about when implementing something like this?